# DDR Timings Vs. Compile Times

Tags: performance, memory, compilation

I wonder how important memory timings are to compile times?

Say, DDR3 1600 vs DDR3 2400.

I've scoured google and relevant data is hard to come by.

There are plenty of articles discussing things like "what are the best upgrades for improving compile times," but they almost always come down to CPU/RAM, and stop there.

Comment: If anyone looking this up wants to speculate, here is a bit of relevant info.
http://www.anandtech.com/show/6372/memory-performance-16gb-ddr31333-to-ddr32400-on-ivy-bridge-igp-with-gskill/11